# ¿como puedo hacer para poder guardar en mi array de sesion solo el contenido de los inputs text seleccionados con un checkbox?

Tags: php

> ¿como puedo hacer para poder guardar en mi array de sesion solo el contenido de los inputs text seleccionados con un checkbox?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="" method="post">

      NOMBRE:<input type="text" name="campo_nombre[]" value=""><input type="checkbox" value="si" name="check[]"><br><br>
      NOMBRE:<input type="text" name="campo_nombre[]" value=""><input type="checkbox" value="si" name="check[]"><br><br>
      NOMBRE:<input type="text" name="campo_nombre[]" value=""><input type="checkbox" value="si" name="check[]"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar" />

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

> En esta parte recorro los 2 arrays pero no consigo obtener los nombres de los campos del formulario que han sido seleccionados mediante el checkbox

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){//leer los datos del formulario
  $name = $_REQUEST['campo_nombre'];
  $check = $_POST['check'];
  foreach($name as $n ) {//recorrer array de input text
    for($i = 0; $i < count($check); $i++){//recorrer arrya de checkbox
      if($check[$i] == "si"){
        $_SESSION["nombres"].=$n;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Quieres que S_SESSION["nombres"] sea una cadena de texto con todos los nombres pegados?  Por que eso es lo que estarás haciendo cuando lo consigas. Bueno, una pista... si cambias esto: `campo_nombre[]` por esto `campo_nombre[x]` donde x es cualquier número o identificador que quieras ponerle, en su input del checkbox siguiente puedes referenciarlo con su value="x", y luego te será más facil asociarlos

Comment: si quiero que S_SESSION["nombres"] sea una cadena, no me importa si es un array, pero de la forma que lo estoy haciendo será una cadena, el problema es que cuando no selecciono un checkbox el array es mas pequeño que el de los nombres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una alternativa seria usando [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-exists.php), ya que van a coincidir las claves de `$_POST['campo_nombre']` con `$_POST['check']`

**Opcion A** (concatenando)

```
session_start(); 
$nombres = '';

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
  // Obtener datos
  $name = $_POST['campo_nombre'] ?? [];
  $check = $_POST['check'] ?? [];
  
  foreach($name as $key => $n ) :    
    if (array_key_exists($key, $check)) :
        // Opcion A
        $nombres .= $n;
        $_SESSION["nombres"]= $nombres;
    endif;        
  endforeach;

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($_SESSION['nombres']);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

Salida:

```
DanielPablo
```

**Opcion B** (array)

```
session_start(); 
$arr = [];

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
  // Obtener datos
  $name = $_POST['campo_nombre'] ?? [];
  $check = $_POST['check'] ?? [];

  // Edit va aqui:
  foreach($name as $key => $n ) :
     // Eliminamos las claves donde el nombre esta vacio ''
     if ($n == '') unset($name[$key]);      
  endforeach;
  
  foreach($name as $key => $n ) :    
    if (array_key_exists($key, $check)) :    
        // Opcion B
        $arr[] = $n;
        $_SESSION["nombres"]= $arr;
    endif;        
  endforeach;

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($_SESSION['nombres']);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

Salida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Pablo
    [1] => Daniel
)
```

**Edit:**

Simplemente le puedes añadir un identificador a la clave de `campo_nombre[1]` y `check[1]` este deberían ser idéntico para así asociar correctamente tu checkbox con cada nombre.

De esta forma pueden existir campos vacíos, no importa en que orden.

```
<form class="" action="" method="post">
    NOMBRE:<input type="text" name="campo_nombre[1]" value=""><input type="checkbox" value="si" name="check[1]"><br><br>
    NOMBRE:<input type="text" name="campo_nombre[2]" value=""><input type="checkbox" value="si" name="check[2]"><br><br>
    NOMBRE:<input type="text" name="campo_nombre[3]" value=""><input type="checkbox" value="si" name="check[3]"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar" />
</form>
```

**Edit**

Para eliminar la posicion del nombre vacio, podrias recorrer antes el array y con unset, lo eliminamos.

```
foreach($name as $key => $n ) :
    // Eliminamos las claves donde el nombre esta vacio ''
    if ($n == '') unset($name[$key]);   
endforeach;
```

Comment: El problema es que si por ejemplo el segundo campo de formulario no se rellena, pero si se rellenan el 1° y 3°, al mostrar los datos el valor del tercer campo no aparece. Además si se deja en blanco un campo pero se pulsa el checkbox me gustaría omitir esa selección de alguna forma a la hora de mostrar los datos ya que me aparecería un nombre vacío. Gracias de antemano, lo he intentado de nuevo pero no acabo de conseguir el resultado correcto.

Comment: @codeJava Simplemente le puedes añadir un identificador a la clave de ```campo_nombre[1]``` y ```check[1]``` este deberían ser idéntico para así asociar correctamente tu checkbox con cada clave. Te he actualizado mi pregunta.

Comment: Solo le falta un problema, u es que cuando se marca un checkbox pero el campo del nombre se deja vacío, entonces el array contiene una posición más y eso me pasaba y ahí estoy atascado

Comment: Podrías recorrer el array antes y con ```unset``` eliminar los que tiene el valor vacío, aunque si las claves tienen relación no debería de importar, al menos en el localhost probe, aunque selecciono el 1 y el 3 y el segundo lo dejo vacío, me obtiene los nombres correctamente del 1 y 3. Déjame ponerte un ejemplo eliminando los inputs vacíos, a ver si con eso se soluciona. Te lo añado a mi pregunta.

Comment: Lo he solucionado asi.                     foreach($name as $key => $n ){  
    if (array_key_exists($key, $check)){
        if($name[$key]!=""){
        // Opcion B
        $arr[] = $n;
        $_SESSION["nombres"]= $arr;
        }
    }       
  }

Comment: Eres un crack!! Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: De nada amigo, me alegro, te he dejo un ejemplo como podrías eliminar los nombres vacíos con ```unset()```.  Si deseas reindexar podrías usar ```array_values()```. Suerte y un saludo.